# Elementary proof of cannonball problem: why can't $n$ be a multiple of $3$?

Tags: number-theory

At the end of the proof of lemma 10, lemma 8 is cited. In order to use it and finish the contradiction, we need to show $n$ is not a multiple of $3.$ However, I don't see any contradiction in having $n \equiv \pm 2 \mod 8$ and $n \equiv 0 \mod 3.$

Proof: https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1990.11995558

Comment: later asked at MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432994/elementary-proof-of-cannonball-problem-why-cant-n-be-a-multiple-of-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the term is $2^s,$ not $n.$